# antd react InputItem ,how to change color and fontSize of the placeholder's text?

Tags: ios, reactjs, antd

antd mobile : InputItem ,how to change color and fontSize of the placeholder's text ?
What's the property?

this is sheetStyle:`inputType:{
        width:width - 70 - 15,
        height:34,
        backgroundColor:'white',
        marginLeft:0,
        marginRight:15,
        borderRadius:5,
        paddingLeft:10,
        paddingRight:5,
    }`

change color and fontSize of the placeholder's text

no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textfont of placeholder is the same with text.Just so change the fontSize ,the placeholder's text fontSize will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This should work.

```
inputType:{
        width:width - 70 - 15,
        height:34,
        backgroundColor:'white',
        marginLeft:0,
        marginRight:15,
        borderRadius:5,
        paddingLeft:10,
        paddingRight:5,
        '&::placeholder': {
            fontSize: 20,
            color: '#FF0000'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.But it's not good.This is the result : "&::placeholder" is not a valid style property.